# Nginx/PHP request times out when viewed through mobile browser

Tags: php, nginx, raspbian

I'm running nginx and php on raspbian as a lightweight way to perform admin functions on a headless setup.

When I test this through a desktop browser, it works fine.  But when I hit the same page through a mobile browser (specifically chrome on an iPhone), it times out.

My nginx configuration is very simple...

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name _;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

and the page itself is also quite simple... to display the list of known wifi networks and add more if required.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Network Admin</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Configured Networks:</h3>
<br>
<?php
exec("sudo /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 list_networks",$wpaNetworkList);

echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<table border=1>\n";
echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:bold\">";
echo "<td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Priority</td><td style=\"text-align:center\">Forget</td><td>Connected</td></tr>\n";

$knownNetworkArray=[];
$i=1;
foreach($wpaNetworkList as $wpaNetwork){
    if($i>1){  // skip first header row 
        $networkArray=explode("\t",$wpaNetwork);

        $networkID    ="${networkArray[0]}";
        $networkName  ="${networkArray[1]}";
        $networkStatus=("${networkArray[3]}"=="[CURRENT]" ? "Yes" : "&nbsp;");

        // add network name to known networks for later
        $knownNetworkArray[]=$networkName;

        // get network priority
        $networkPriority=exec("sudo /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 get_network $networkID priority");

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$networkID</td>";
        echo "<td>$networkName</td>";

        switch ($networkPriority) {
            case "2":
                echo "<td>High</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
                break;
            case "1":
                echo "<td>Medium</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
                break;
            default:
                echo "<td>Low</td><td style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"forget\" onclick=\"document.location.href='forget.php?network=$networkID';\" /></td>";
        }

        echo "<td>$networkStatus</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
?>

<br><br>
<h3>Available Networks:</h3>
Here are the latest Scan results:<br>
<br>
<?php
exec("sudo /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results",$availableNetworkList);

echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<table border=1>\n";
echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:bold\">";
echo "<td>Signal Strength</td><td>Flags</td><td>Name</td><td style=\"text-align:center\">Add</td></tr>\n";

$i=1;
foreach($availableNetworkList as $availableNetwork){
    if($i>1){  // skip first header row
        $availableArray=explode("\t",$availableNetwork);
        $availableSignal="${availableArray[2]}";
        $availableFlags ="${availableArray[3]}";
        $availableName  ="${availableArray[4]}";
        $availableKnown =(in_array("$availableName",$knownNetworkArray) ? "(already added)" : "<input type=\"button\" value=\"add\" onclick=\"document.location.href='add.php?ssid=$availableName';\" />");

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$availableSignal</td>";
        echo "<td>$availableFlags</td>";
        echo "<td>$availableName</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\">$availableKnown</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
?>
<br><br>

<form action="" method="post">
Click <input type="button" value="rescan" onclick="document.location.href='rescan.php';" /> to do a new scan for available networks.
<br><br>
Or  <input type="button" value="add manual" onclick="document.location.href='add.php';" /> to add a new network manually.
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

To complete the description of the use-case... it's a headless Raspberry Pi Zero W.  This little web interface is to add/remove wifi networks to wlan0, and I have hostapd running to host a virtual interface (uap0) on the same adaptor (wlan0) which I can always connect to for the admin functions.

It all works fine when testing through a desktop browser (Chrome), but when I try through a mobile browser the page usually times out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: Additional Info**
If I remove the two lines retrieving data, the page loads on the mobile browsers...

```
exec("sudo /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 list_networks",$wpaNetworkList);  
exec("sudo /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results",$availableNetworkList);
```

albeit with the expected php errors for undefined arrays.

Can't figure out why this would stop the page completing on some browsers but not others

Comment: This case reminds me when I wasn't be able to access local web server from the phone connected via my local WiFi because of Chrome traffic compression ([Lite Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284)), but it isn't available for iOS. Maybe some other program (e.g. VPN) makes your request going to some external server first? Check the nginx access logs, maybe your request not arrived to your server at all?

Comment: Thanks for advice, but can definitely see the request in access.log